# How do I persist parameters in a user's session without appending to destination URL?

Tags: parameter-passing

What I want to do is take the URL parameters from a previous page and append them to the destination page without changing the destination link on the initial page.

so if I have www.website.com/?parameter=value

and someone clicks this URL - www.website.com/page2

When that user actually lands on page2, the ?parameter=value is appended to the destination page URL like so:

www.website.com/page2?parameter=value

I would like to do this without having the click URL on the initial page include the params.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want them on the url line? An obvious choice is to store them in the session when  www.website.com is requested, then grab them from session when handling page2.